# text overlapped in textfield

Tags: cocoa

I am using NSTextField object in my window.When i hide and unhide the window, the text in the textfield gets overlapped. Previous text gets retain on the textfield. So, when i typed again, it looks texts are not cleared in the textfield.

I set string as

```
[myStringField setStringValue:@""];
```

But, it does not work.
I am attaching a snapshot below. My query is why the texts gets overlapped.

[image]

Regards,

Comment: It doesn't seem like previous texts are retained. Probably you are creating the text field every time you show the window.

Comment: Have you connected the iboutlet correctly, if not then setStringValue will not be executing?

Comment: @EmptyStack: I am loading from nib file so there is no chance of creating new NSTextfield object every time. Once nib is loaded, i set it to my member instance, so next time when window is shown, no loading is required form Nib. Seems some thing related with field editor. its not clearing, but when i do some other actions in window and come back to textfield it clears after some operations.

Comment: I created new UI object replacing the old ones...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to create new nib. Its pretty difficult to handle field editor.